# remove duplicates in a string with a buffer

Tags: c

I’m trying to remove duplicates in a string using a map. Running it through GDB I'm not able to figure out where the code is failing, though the logic to me seems right.
Could anyone please point out the mistake?

```
int main() {

    char *str="I had my morning tea";
    int len = strlen(str);
    int dupArr[256] = {0};

    //Build the map
    int i=0;
    for(i;i<256;i++)
        dupArr[str[i]]++;

    //If the count is 1 then print that value.
    i=0;
    for(i;i<256;i++) {
        if(dupArr[str[i]] == 1) {
            printf("%c\n",str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
I h y o r i g t % c 4  @ } ` 8 � F J
```

I get up to 't' ,which is correct but then i see magic chars.

Comment: `str[i]` is accessing memory it shouldn't. The `str` array is only `len+1` characters in size but you ignore the length and continue all the way up to 256. The first loop condition should be `i<len` instead of `i<256. And the last `if` should be `if(dupArr[i] == 1)` instead of `if(dupArr[str[i]] == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Your string has length of `len` but you are traversing `till 256` which is `out of bound.`
`Use len` when inserting into the hash.

```
    int i=0;
    for(i;i<LEN;i++)
      dupArr[str[i]]++;
```

Also if your are checking the duplicates then it should be `bigger than 1` since your are `++` the first encountered char

```
if(dupArr[str[i]] > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Mark Ezberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69937683/2410359)'s good answer, note that `dupArr[str[i]]++;` poses a problem when `str[i] < 0`.

Better to treat the characters as `unsigned char`:

```
int dupArr[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {0};
....
dupArr[(unsigned char) str[i]]++;
```

---

Rolling this and other ideas together:

```
int main(void) {
  char *str="I had my morning tea";

  size_t dupArr[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {0};

  unsigned char *s = (unsigned char *) str;
  while (*s) {
    dupArr[*s]++;
    s++; 
  }

  for(unsigned i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; i++) {
    // A duplicate is when dupArr[i] is _more_ than 1.
    if(dupArr[i] > 1) {
      printf("%c\n",str[i]);
    }
  }
}
```